# Help with integration of a function over the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to compute the following integral
$$\int_0^1 r dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{1+r e^{i \theta}}{\left(1-r e^{i \theta}\right)^3}f(r,\theta) $$
assuming that the function $f$ is regular in the disk. 
I expect this integral to be related to $f(1,0)$ but I have no idea of how to prove it.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You can write the inner-most integral as a contour integral over the circle $|z| = r$, and evaluate using the residue theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried to but I was not able to conclude the computation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking $f(r,\theta)$ to mean $f(re^{i\theta})$, the inner integral is the same as the contour integral

$$\oint_{|z| = r} \frac{dz}{iz} \frac{1 + z}{(1 - z)^3}f(z)$$

Since $0 < r < 1$, the function $\frac{1+z}{i(1 - z)^3}f(z)$ is regular inside and on the circle $|z| = r$. By the Cauchy integral formula this integral evaluates to $$2\pi i\frac{1+0}{i(1-0)^3}f(0) = 2\pi f(0)$$ Your integral reduces to $\int_0^1 2\pi f(0)\, r\, dr = \pi f(0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, there is no contribution from the pole in 1 at r=1? However, I really meant a generic function that depends independently of $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Hi @PietroDona, if the domain of integration of the $r$-integral contained $1$ in its interior, e.g., if the $r$-limits were from $0$ to $2$, then there would be a contribution from the pole at $r = 1$. If the function $f$ is just some generic function of $r$ and $\theta$, what do you mean when you say that $f$ is regular? Usually, the term regular means analytic in this context.